# Changing code on Wix - Possible?

Tags: permissions, velo

I have a co-worker with a Wix site and I was wondering if it is possible to edit the code?  I went on the account but I couldn't find any options. I have searched google, and also tried to contact the people who run the site but I can't find any helpful information.  I feel like there has to be *some* way of doing it but none I have found so far.  I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit the HTML source in Wix sites with either the free or upgraded versions. You can add a widget of your own HTML, which is about the closest you can get.

Here is a relevant support thread from the Wix site. It seems you cannot even have them customize your code.
https://www.wix.com/support/html5/ticket/13990942-5c54-48b9-84f0-b664ae22af77